# Throwing an exception like "Operation time out"

Tags: asp.net, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to upload file on oracle cloud infrastructure iaas but found error like operation time out while writing stream using GetRequestStream().Please also check whether the file that I trying to post is in correct order or not.

```
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);
            byte[] filebyte =FileUpload1.FileBytes;

            var postdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filebyte.ToString());


            var tenancyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCTenancyId"];
            var userId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCUserId"];
            var fingerprint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCFingerprint"];
            var privateKeyPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCPrivateKeyPath"];
            var privateKeyPassphrase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCPrivateKeyPassphrase"];

            var signer = new RequestSigner(tenancyId, userId, fingerprint, privateKeyPath, privateKeyPassphrase);

           // ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var uri = new Uri($"https://objectstorage.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/");

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.SendChunked = true;
            request.ContentType = "text/plain";
             request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
            request.ContentLength =postdata.Length;



        try
        {

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(postdata, 0, postdata.Length);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("testing"+ex.Message+"Tedting");

        }



            request.Headers["x-content-sha256"] = Convert.ToBase64String(SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(postdata));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the URL to the following format:

```
var uri = new Uri($"https://objectstorage.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/n/{namespaceName}/b/{bucketName}/o/{objectName}");
```

Docs: https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/Object/PutObject

If you are still receiving an error after updating the URL please edit the question to include the full error you are getting.